# How can I override super class property with same name in OpenAPI Spec 3.0?

Tags: swagger, openapi, openapi-generator, swagger-codegen, openapi-generator-maven-plugin

I have two schemas
Order and ProductOrder, ProductOrder inherits the Order schema properties using allOf.
Now, I have a common property product (an array) but with different items type for both

So, while generating the code I'm getting an error
name clash have the same erasure, yet neither overrides the other

I am expecting that both model achieve inheritance after code generation and I can have the property names as it is

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.